# Keep Hive session open EMR

Tags: bash, hive, hiveql, amazon-emr

I’m running a bash script on AWS EMR that does something like:

```
for i in (‘tab1’ ‘tab2’ ‘tab3’ ‘tab4’)
  do
   nrow=$(hive -e “select count(*) from $i”) 
  done
```

This takes time as for each count a new hive session have to be setup.
Is there a way to keep the session open throughout the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all counts in a single statement. You can also generate the SQL statement instead of hardcoding.

Something like this:

```
output=$(hive -S -e "select 'tab1', count(*) from tab1
                     union all 
                     select 'tab2', count(*) from tab2
                     union all 
                     select 'tab3', count(*) from tab3")

echo "$output" | while read TABLE_NAME COUNT
do
echo "$TABLE_NAME $COUNT"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Will write the statement in a separate file and submit it in a single session.